# Dividing a string to portions SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm try to cut the this string to 3 or 4 parts must only contains maximum of 40 characters. If the 40th character is between a word i must go find the last space and it cut and put into ADDRESS 1, then from i stop i must recount again to 40 character and if the 40th character is still in a middle of a word i must go back and find the last space and so on so forth until the whole string is divided.
Here is my current code and im out of idea. Hope you can help me.

```
declare @test varchar(150)
set @test = 'GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I DOOR 10 2F SJRDC BLDG PHASE 1 INSULAR SUBD LANANG'



Select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
                len(Substring(@test,0,40)))),len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
                CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
                len(Substring(@test,0,40)))))  



Select Substring(@test,
Len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
len(Substring(@test,0,40)))
)),40),
len(Substring(@test,Len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
len(Substring(@test,0,40)))
)),40))             



Select SUBSTRING(@test,((len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
                CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
                len(Substring(@test,0,40)))))+2) + 
                len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
                CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
                len(Substring(@test,0,40))))) +4 )
                , 40), lEN(sUBSTRING(@test,((len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
                CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
                len(Substring(@test,0,40)))))+2) + 
                len(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40)),
                CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Substring(@test,0,40))),
                len(Substring(@test,0,40))))) +4 )
                , 40))
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks.. i think ill rest first..and go back with this tomorrow..

Comment: The only way i can (honestly), see doing this is with a recursive CTE, and that isn't going to perform great.

Comment: I recommend address parsing software, no matter what you try you will not get it right without many many hours of programming.  If it does not need USPS certification for mailing at a discount then you can get a nice tool for under $500.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather simple algorithm you can use (schematically presented, not actual running code):

1. Declare variables @_Chunk_Start INT = 1 , @_Chunk_End INT = 40 , @_Test_End VARCHAR(3),
2. Create a loop,
3. Retrieve three as `SET @Test_End = SUBSTRING(@test,@_Chunk_Start + 38 , 3)
4. This will give you the 39th, 40th and 41st chars;
5. "in the middle of the word" means that all 3 chars are letters;
6. If the 40th char is a blank or the 40th char is not a blank but the 41st is, chop from @_Chunk_Start to @_Chunk_Start  + 39,
7. If the 40th and 41st chars are not a blank, enter a small loop decreasing the value of @_Chunk_End by one till you get a blank; chop, set the new value for @_Chunk_Start to be @_Chunk_End + 1 and go to the next cycle of the main loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A rather pragmatic but rather fast approach, suitable for **short** words and omitting any high sophisticated logic, is this:

```
declare @test varchar(150)
set @test = 'GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I DOOR 10 2F SJRDC BLDG PHASE 1 INSULAR SUBD LANANG';

WITH Splittable(Casted) AS 
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' +  REPLACE((SELECT @test AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) 
)
,Counted AS
(
    SELECT part.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Part
          ,LEN(part.value('.','nvarchar(max)'))+1 AS LengthWithBlank 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNr
    FROM Splittable
    CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes('/x') AS B(part)
)
,Grouped AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,SUM(LEN(Part)) OVER(ORDER BY RowNr) /40 AS Grp
    FROM Counted
)
SELECT g1.Grp
      ,(SELECT g2.Part + ' '
        FROM Grouped AS g2
        WHERE g2.Grp=g1.Grp
        ORDER BY g2.RowNr
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
       ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM Grouped AS g1
GROUP BY g1.Grp;
```

This will first split the string to its words and return them ordered and with a length to each part.

The cumulated `SUM() OVER()` is *integer-divided* by 40, which results in "groups". The final select will return each group With a result like this:

```
Grp [splitted text]
0   GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I GTB INDUSTRIAL 
1   NETWORK DAVAO I DOOR 10 2F SJRDC BLDG PHASE 1 
2   INSULAR SUBD LANANG
```

### HINT

This is approach **is not exact!** (Some result is larger than 40), but quite okay with many short words. You might take the result of the CTE "Grouped" to continue with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Recursive CTE` approach. Your string is not that long, so you can copy recursive part several times to do it without recursion.

```
declare @test varchar(150)
set @test = 'GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I DOOR 10 2F SJRDC BLDG PHASE 1 INSULAR SUBD LANANG'

;with cte as (
    select @test txt, cast('' as varchar(200)) res
    union all
    select
        cast(stuff(txt, 1, len(lres) + 1, '') as varchar(150)), cast(lres as varchar(200))c
    from
        cte
        cross apply (select reverse(substring(txt, 1, 40)) rev_txt) ca2
        cross apply (select reverse(right(rev_txt, len(rev_txt) - charindex(' ', rev_txt))) isspace) ca4
        cross apply (select case when substring(txt, 41, 1) = ' ' then substring(txt, 1, 40) else isspace end lres) ca5
    where
        len(txt) > 0
)

select res from cte
where len(res) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I place this as a new answer, as it is a completely different approach then my first answer. It is exact, but not so fast:

```
declare @test varchar(150)
set @test = 'GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I GTB INDUSTRIAL NETWORK DAVAO I DOOR 10 2F SJRDC BLDG PHASE 1 INSULAR SUBD LANANG';

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT @test AS Original 
          ,1 AS StartPos
          ,SUBSTRING(@test,1,1) AS SingleChar
          ,1 AS RunningPos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Original
          ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@test,RunningPos +1,1)=' ' AND CHARINDEX(' ',Original,RunningPos+2)-StartPos >=40 THEN RunningPos+2 ELSE StartPos END 
          ,SUBSTRING(@test,RunningPos +1,1) AS SingleChar
          ,RunningPos +1
    FROM recCTE 
    WHERE RunningPos<LEN(Original)
)
,GroupedCharacterList AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM recCTE
)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((
        SELECT SingleChar AS [*]
        FROM GroupedCharacterList AS gl2
        WHERE gl2.StartPos=gl.StartPos
        ORDER BY gl2.RunningPos
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')))
FROM GroupedCharacterList AS gl
GROUP BY StartPos
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The recursive CTE will read character by character. If a blank is found, it looks for the next blank in the string and does some computation. If the **next** blank exceeds the maximum length, the current blank is the new `StartPos` and the process continues.

This is finally grouped and reconcatenated